# Polynominal error in Rapidminer when doing n-gram classification

Tags: svm, libsvm, n-gram, rapidminer, concept

I am trying to classify different concepts in a text using n-gram. My data tyically exists of six columns:

1. The word that needs classification
2. The classification
3. First word on the left of 1)
4. Second word on the left of 1)
5. First word on the right of 1)
6. Second word on the right of 1)

When I try to use a SVM in Rapidminer, I get the error that it can not handle polynominal values. I know that this can be done because I have read it in different papers. I set the second column to 'label' and have tried to set the rest to 'text' or 'real', but it seems to have no effect. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `Support Vector Machine (LibSVM)` Operator.
In contrast to the classic SVM which only supports two class problems, the LibSVM implementation  (http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf) supports multi-class classification as well as regression.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to create attributes with names equal to the words and values equal to the distance from the word of interest. Of course, all possible words would need to be represented as attributes so the input data would be large.